# Get Facebook fanpage status using Facebook app access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to retrieve Facebook page statuses using an app access token?

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) I could use "any valid access_token or user access_token" but when I try to use the application access token I'm getting the following message: "A user access token is required to request this resource.". Am I generating the app access token in a wrong way? Is there anyway to access the statuses of a public Facebook fan page without a user?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a **user** `access_token` is required to query this connection.

Tried without any `access_token` in the Graph API Explorer on [redbull page](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/7848140588/?method=GET&path=redbull/statuses?limit=3) and the result was:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
    "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}
```

But after providing an app `access_token`:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
    "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}
```

This is a bit misleading!

Comment: Is there a demographic/geographic restriction on the page? If there is, you must use a user access token for a user who meets the restrictions. If not, any access token (page, app, user) should work - if this isn't the case it's a bug

Comment: (Incidentally, i was able to access /redbull/feed and /redbull/statuses with a page access token for a different page - maybe it's just an issue with app access tokens)

Comment: I've created a page without any restrictions and couldn't retrieve all statuses. I think the documentation is wrong =(

Comment: @Igy, so your second comment implies that this is a bug? If so please create it and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if your still facing this issue. But here's a workaround :

By asking the graph API, you have this issue, but by using the FQL langage, it works perfectly with an App ID!

Here's an example for the 'PSG' page :

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT post_id, type, attachment, message FROM stream WHERE source_id IN(SELECT page_id from page where username='PSG')&access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

;)